# How to get the highest pc picture quality output to tv

Tags: windows-7, vga, resolution, hdtv, 1080p

What's the best possible way to get the highest quality picture on my HDTV..

I have a Panasonic 65vt30 1080p 600hz

What I have setup now is just the pc hooked up to my tv thru VGA , running win7 & the highest resolution I'm able to set is 1280x1024 - Refresh rate: 60hz - color depth 32-bit

maybe I'm wrong but to me it looks like I'm only getting about 1/3 of what I could actually get

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should tell us the GPU in your PC and the type of video connectors it has besides VGA.  BTW the max res that your TV will accept on its "PC input" is a WXGA resolution of 1280x768 (unusual for a consumer-grade TV), which is  essentially the same as 720p video.  720p is considered one half the spatial resolution of 1080i/p.

Comment: So if I was to order a VGA to HDMI adapter would that give me the 1080p resolution & refresh rate I'm trying to get?

Comment: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Eforcity+-+VGA+to+HDMI+Cable+M/M+-+6Ft+-+Black/4515769.p?id=1218479550069&skuId=4515769&ref=06&loc=01&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=4515769

Comment: This seems to be the cheapest route , every other way seems like it would cost me over 200 bucks not including I don't even know how to open a computer

Comment: That VGA-to-HDMI cable is bogus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analog signal through VGA cable is limited, and most HDTVs don't support high-def resolution through it.

Get an HDMI cable. This will make you TV Plug'n'Play and use the digital signal. It will let you set TV's native resolution of 1920x1080. If You don't have an HDMI output to the computer, you should have a DVI output and you'll have to buy a DVI-to-HDMI adapter.

Comment: You definitely want to go digital HDMI to the TV.

Comment: HDMI will only work if your PC/Graphics card has a HDMI port... If not use DVI... If you don't have that - get a decent graphics card! ;)

Comment: *"Analog signal through VGA cable is limited"* - Ever since the VESA standards were established, it has been the display end that has been the limiting factor.  Resolutions like 2560x1600 are possible on the VGA port from modern GPUs.

Comment: @sawdust you are right. That's why I blamed the HDTVs on the second part of the sentence. Most PC monitors do support the native resolution through VGA cables.

Comment: Radoo , if I was to order a VGA to HDMI adapter would that give me the 1080p resolution & refresh rate I'm trying to get?

Comment: No. You need to have digital signal from one device to another. Than means only DVI, HDMI or/and Display Port cables from one to another. Firstly you need the output of your computer to be digital, so you can't use the VGA port.

Comment: *"Get an HDMI cable"* - A poorly worded answer, especially considering that the OP is looking at a bogus "VGA-to-HDMI cable".  Three sentences later you qualify that answer with "if you don't have an [sic] HDMI output ...".  In programming languages the construct is **if** () **then** {}.  There is no **do** {} **if** () construct simply because it is a writing style that is harder to understand.